# Can I have separate playlist for each node?

Tags: 7

I have this problem:
I have a nodetype Audiobook.
In this page I set title, ahthor, description and other informations.
I want to insert episodes of this audiobook in a playlist that user can display on audiobook page.
When user clicks on an episode, it plays automatically.
I'm trying to use mediafront, but I must create a view for each list, it's tedious.
I tried to use nodehierarchy, by creating a content tuype "episode", but, when I click on one it opens a page and I can't switch to next easily.
Any idea? I searched the internet, but there's doesn't seem to be no module.

Comment: I haven't used media front so I am not sure of this.
I'd use entity reference and pass an id in the url as a contextual filter. That way you can have one list that adapts to whatever audiobook/episode you are viewing. Have you tried that?

Comment: No, I will try now entityreference, I never used it... :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want a second content type called episodes. You can do this by adding a relationship between the audiobook and episodes with an [entity reference](https://www.drupal.org/project/entityreference) field. When creating the field you can define how the relationship works. Episodes can then be ordered and you can setup a single view to display the episodes for a particular audiobook in which ever way you choose. The view would accept the audiobook node id as an argument selecting episodes by relationship for extra ease of development and simplicity.

You could also use the inline entity form module to add and edit related entities.

Comment: Paragraphs would also be another alternative to Inline Entity Form.